# Unity game for tvos not registering input in Apple TV simulator

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, tvos

I have built a simple 2d game in unity with a main menu screen in unity for apple's tvOS.

However, when I run it in xcode simulator (Apple TV 4K (2nd generation), Apple TV (1E59...D4E)), it does not get any input from keyboard not even when I change input system of unity from old to new.

I even tried to run a sample scene from a [paid plugin for tvos controls](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/tvos-easy-input-helper-for-apple-tv-49843) from unity asset store. No matter which button I click its not responding to any input.

My question is if there is any problem with running a unity game in tvOS simulator in xcode. Or is there something wrong in my code or settings.

I am new to game development so I may be overlooking something. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: When i ran it on apple tv it just works with siri remote. no issues on an actual apple tv just not working on simulator for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Using the InputDebugger from Unity even it detects the iOsGameController but nothing happens when you move the dpad. Values don't change on that window:

[image]

Edit: I found on the official doc that apparently it is not supported (look at Known limitations) https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/Manual/tvOS.html